# How does labelled N from tyrosine appear in phenylalanine if the latter is an essential amino acid?

Tags: biochemistry, amino-acids

A [certain question](https://www1.udel.edu/chem/white/C643/643FinalF11.pdf) (not my course or instructor or even university) goes:

> Exposed to regular metabolic activity in a rat liver, a <sup>13</sup>C label in tyrosine will not appear as a <sup>13</sup>C label in phenylalanine. However, a <sup>15</sup>N label from tyrosine will appear in phenylalanine (among other amino acids) under the same conditions.
>
> Explain and show why this is so using appropriate structures and reactions.

Tyrosine metabolism is well-discussed in any undergraduate biochemistry text and takes the following route (courtesy Voet, 5e):[image: Metabolism of Tyrosine]

Since phenylalanine hydroxylase catalyzes an irreversible reaction,<sup>1</sup> radiolabels ought not to distribute back from tyrosine to phenylalanine. Where am I going wrong?

#### Footnotes

1: Remember that phenylalanine is an essential amino acid and cannot be synthesized in animals.

Comment: What does "Exposed to regular metabolic activity in a rat liver" mean? This phrase seems to apply to radioactive labelled atoms, which is linguistic nonsense. Does the question really say this, or have you garbled it? It smells a little of a trick. And are the rats growing or adult, and did the question say that Phe is an essential amino acid in rats? I cannot find a definitive source for that.

Comment: I suspect that the answer might be that there is some phenylpyruvate in rat liver, and that this can be transaminated to phenylalanine using glutamate, the N of which would have become labelled from the Tyr to OH-Pyruvate reaction, but glutamate C would not. This would require that rat liver had enough phenylalanine deaminase to generate phenylpyruvate from dietary amino acids, and that some sort of cycling occurs. I have not provided this as an answer because I don't know if it is true. I can find some papers that suggest these enzymes are present, but the whole things seems rather obscure.

Comment: OK, I checked the original paper. The question is just badly phrased.

Comment: I simplified the title. A label is a label. We don't need to know what isotope it is, which solves the problem of the superscript.

Comment: This isn’t really a question that most people would be able to answer without reading a lot of literature. I suspect the professor of this course taught a case study about phenylalanine metabolism, which would make it an appropriate question for an exam. My guess is the same as @David ‘s: cycling by a [transaminase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylalanine(histidine)_transaminase). It’s of note that this enzyme is related to the metabolic disorder phenylketonuria, which make’s it use in a case study more likely.

Comment: @canadianer — Agreed. Doesn't look as if there is a suitable deaminase in mammals, but there are reports of a phenylalinine/glutamine transaminase. Of course the reaction would have to be in an equilibrium that allowed the generation of some hydroxy-pyruvate and its reversal, which is perhaps what the "regular metabolic activity" is intended to imply. I don't think data on that are easy to come by. Most of the papers I can find are from the 70s.